# Entering text in pop up and saving it on TestNG

Tags: selenium, popup, window

I'm new to automation testing. I'm using twitter as a test website to learn selenium.

I want to create a new tweet and for doing that I'm using the below scenario. I'm able to open the 'New tweet' pop-up but still can't enter text in its text box. Please help.

Pre-Requisite: Login into Twitter

1. Click on the button (for creating new tweet) on top right side of screen.
   The pop up opens up
2. Click on the text box present on pop-up to enter text.
   The cursor gets highlighted in text box and save button enables
3. Enter some text
4. Click on Save button

For me it's working till point 2 and after that it doesn't enter text in textbox

See my code below:

```
String popUpHandle = driver.getWindowHandle(); 

driver.switchTo().window(popUpHandle);

driver.findElement(By.id("global-new-tweet-button")).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//button[@type='button'])[123]")).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//button[@type='button'])[123]")).sendKeys("test tweet");

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='button'])[106]")).click();
```

Comment: does it throw an exception?

Answer (score 0):

@user3241182

I just tested this myself. You do not need to use any window handling.
Code Below is a provided solution and works great.

```
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://twitter.com/");
    WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.id("signin-email"));
    username.clear();
    username.sendKeys("your_twitter_handle");
    WebElement pass = driver.findElement(By.id("signin-password"));
    pass.clear();
    pass.sendKeys("your_twitter_passwd");
    WebElement signInButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/form/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/button"));
    signInButton.click();
    WebElement tweetButton = driver.findElement(By.id("global-new-tweet-button"));
    tweetButton.click();
    WebElement tweetBox = driver.findElement(By.id("tweet-box-global"));
    tweetBox.clear();
    tweetBox.sendKeys("This is an automated tweet!");
    WebElement tweetSubmit = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[9]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[2]/div[2]/button"));
    tweetSubmit.click();
```